# android onBindViewHolder is not implemented even it is implemented using extends

Tags: android

When implementing card viewed recycler view, I had a problem. I implemented `onBindViewHolder` in class which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`. But I want to use `ViewHolder` which extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. The problem is, when I use custom `ViewHolder`, android studio says you are not implemented `onBindViewHolder`. I don't know how to do it. Are there any masters of android?

Here is my source code.

```
package com.example.beyongha.zipv2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CardHeaderRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1;

Context context;
List<Item> items;
int item_layout;


public CardHeaderRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items, int item_layout) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.item_layout = item_layout;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Item item = items.get(position);
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, item.getImage());
    holder.image.setBackground(drawable);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == 0) ? VIEW_TYPE_HEADER : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_cardview, null);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}





static class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    CardView cardview;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the Adapter using your **CardHeaderRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder** in the generic type parameter

```
public class CardHeaderRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardHeaderRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
```